# Gravity Center not working for Sanskrit Font

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, alignment

I am required to use center-aligned Sanskrit fonts. I am able to display Sanskrit fonts using the following code, but the text is not centered on screen.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL| Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mangal.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
tv.setText(R.string.string1);
```

Comment: do you have any parent layout on which you are going to add tv ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
android:layout_gravity=center
```

in the parent layout of the text view.

Comment: I have tried this also.. for dynamically created child. Text gets center proper if I am entering text in English. But if in the same textview I enter Sanskrit text. It does not work.